# Como enviar un dato desde una Activity a una clase que extiende de View

Tags: android-studio

Pues eso, soy nuevo en esto de la programación y en la comunidad así que mis disculpas si no me sé comportar, la cosa es que estoy intentando enviar un parámetro desde una Activity **Datos** hacia una clase **Lienzo** pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, he intentado enviar los parámetros desde **Datos** con *intent.putExtra* y recibirlos en **Lienzo** con *getIntent()* pero debido a que **Lienzo** es una clase el método no funciona.

la clase **Lienzo** extiende de **View** porque la utilizo como un contenedor **Canvas**.

```
public class Lienzo extends View {
```

Agradecería mucho la ayuda y sugerencias si no me doy a entender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien describes, la clase `View` no extiende de `Activity` por esta razón no puedes recibir un `bundle` conteniendo datos.

En el caso en el cual la no pueda recibir datos mediante un `bundle`, una opción es enviar los datos en el constructor:

```
public class Lienzo extends View {

private String datoRecibido1;
private int datoRecibido2;

 public Lienzo(Context context, String dato1, int dato2) {
        super(context);

      this.datoRecibido1 = dato1;
      this.datoRecibido2 = dato2;
  }

...
...
}
```

de esta forma al instanciar tu clase puedes enviar valores:

```
View myView = new View(getApplicationContext, 12, "Nery");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha venido perfecto!